# Icon.png file not getting copied into Distribution bundle

Tags: iphone, xcode, release, distribution

...yet my Icon@2x.png file is getting copied into there. I checked the Targets on both of the icon files, and they're fine. And both files are listed under Targets->[AppName]->Copy Bundle Resources.

Any idea what might be going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem. My Icon.png file showed a bit of dithering, betraying that perhaps it wasn't really a PNG. I re-saved it as a PNG, and now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the image file is in your project subdirectory? I sometimes put images in there and forget to click the "Copy items into destination group's folder".

Comment: Yes, it's there. But to be honest, why would that matter? As long as Xcode has a proper reference to it, what does it matter where the file is located on my drive?

Comment: Generally it wouldn't, except in certain cases. Such as passing the project from one comp to another.